# Reading a tuple from contract with Drizzle

Tags: solidity, web3js, react-component, truffle, drizzle

Using ContractData from drizzle/react-components to try and call a read function that returns multiple parameters from a struct

MyComponent.js

```
<div>
    <h2>Get Participant Details</h2>
        <ContractData
            drizzle={drizzle}
            drizzleState={drizzleState}
            contract="supplyChain"
            method="getParticipantDetails"
            methodArgs={[1, "modelNumber"]}
        />
```

Solidity Contract

```
 struct participant {
    string userName;
    string password;
    string participantType;
    address participantAddress;
}
function getParticipantDetails(uint32 _p_id) public view returns (string,address,string) {
    return (participants[_p_id].userName, participants[_p_id].participantAddress, participants[_p_id].participantType);
}
```

Not sure how to exactly read a tuple with Drizzle

Answer (score 0):

can help you https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle/blob/develop/ui-tests/react-redux/src/MyComponent.js

From Row:188 for contract ComplexStorage

but I see Error Tags for methodArgs add:

```
Add   :methodArgs="[1, "modelNumber"]"

<ContractData drizzle={drizzle} drizzleState={drizzleState} contract="supplyChain" method="getParticipantDetails" :methodArgs="[1,"modelNumber"]" />
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30480231)

Comment: ok excuse me, i've read bad the question, I focused in the html tags, because in the methodArgs, add :